# How does this function for calculating modular exponentiation work ?

Tags: algorithms, theory, numbers

I know that the rule in maths for modulus is this:

```
ab mod n =(a mod n ) (b mod n) mod n
```

I have found the following code for computing the modular exponentiation:

```
pow(base,exponent,modulus){
 if (exponent==0) return 1;
 else {
  newexp=pow((base*base)%modulus,exponent/2,modulus)
  if (exponent%2 != 0){
    return (base*newexp)%modulus;
      }
  else return (newexp%modulus);
  }
```

However, I do not understand how this code relates to the theory and why it produces a correct result. Can someone explain me how it implements the theory?

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47486857/modular-exponentiation-explanation "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Comment: a^(2b+1) = a(a^2b) = a((a^2)^b). Take mod n of each factor. Repeat dividing the exponent by 2 until it's trivial.

Comment: @gnat i posted because nobody was answering in stack overflow , anyway since someone replied here , i delete the question on stack overflow. Thanks though , cause i didn't know i couldn't do that

Comment: This question is not out of scope.  This question asks for a justification why the exposed algorithm is correct.  It's not a question about debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look how this equality

```
ab mod n =(a mod n ) (b mod n) mod n.
```

explains your algorithm.

The whole trick is to think about the three possibilities for `exponent`:  it can be null, if can be even or it can be odd.

**If `exponent` is 0**, it's easy:  any number raised to the power of exponent 0 is 1.  This is your first return statement.

**If `exponent` is even**, then `exponent%2` is 0.  This means that you can write the exponent as `2*k`, where k is `exponent/2` :

```
pow(a,exponent,n) = a^exponent mod n 
                  = a^(2*k) mod n 
                  = (a^2)^k mod n 
                  = (a*a)^k mod n
                  = pow (a*a, k, n)
                  = pow (a*a, exponent/2, n)
                  = newexp
```

As this expression is modulo n,  applying modulo n once more will not change it,, so it's the same as `newexp % n`.  Here you have the explanation for your last return statement.

**If `exponent` is odd**, then `exponent%2` is 1.  This means that you can write the exponent as `2*k+1`, where k is `exponent/2` (integer division):

```
pow(a,exponent,n) = a^exponent mod n 
                  = a^(2*k+1) mod n 
                  = (a^(2k)*a) mod n
                  = (a^(2k) mod n) * (a mod n) mod n
                  = ((a^2)^k mod n) * (a mod n) mod n
                  = ((a*a)^k mod n) * (a mod n) mod n
                  = pow (a*a, k, n) * (a mod n) mod n
```

Because `pow(a*a, k, n)` is a number modulo n, we know that:

```
pow(a*a, k, n) mod n = pow(a*a, k, n)
```

So we can continue our equality:

```
pow(a,exponent,n) = pow (a*a, k, n) * (a mod n) mod n    
                  = (pow (a*a, k, n) mod n) * (a mod n) mod n
                  = (a*pow (a*a, k, n)) mod n
                  = (a*pow (a*a, exponent/2, n)) mod n
                  = (a*newexp) mod n
```

And here you have the explanation for the second return statement.

Comment: Just when i understood it myself , you answered me , but your explanation is very good. Anyway , i think another explanation is this : it uses the property (A)^B mod C= ((A mod C)^B) mod C
example:
if i have an even exponent : 9^6
then it calls (9^2 mod 6) ^3 mod 6
and it breaks it down again 
because 2 is even again 
9^2 mod 6 = (9 mod 6)(9 mod 6) mod 6